# How can I (using JavaScript) generate a downloadable directory and place my generated files into that directory?

Tags: javascript, download, directory, generate

I'm trying to generate React files already set up to import their children, all placed into a single downloadable folder.

Generating the individual files was easy, but I cannot figure out how to generate a folder and place these files into it.

Browser compatibility is not an issue.
Is this even possible? Could browser security be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

The **HTTP(S)** protocol only allows the transfer (download) of files, the best you can do is to create an archive (`rar`, `zip`, etc.) that contains the folder and transfer that.